# Use jsx to write vue component，How to bind the event with sync modifier？

Tags: events, vue.js, jsx

Here is MyCompnent

```
props: ['visible']
  methods: {
    update () {
     this.$emit('update:visible')
  }
}
```

I use this component in jsx:

```
<MyComponent visible={this.visible} {...{['on-update:visible']: console.log}} />
```

but can not bind the event.

so how to bind this event in jsx.

Answer (score 1):

I have find the answer from the example https://github.com/vuejs/babel-plugin-transform-vue-jsx/blob/master/example/example.js

It cant write like this:

```
<MyComponent visible={this.visible} {...{on:{'update:visible': console.log}} />
```